# How to prove that the recursion works for all numbers?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have the following code to find a^n recursively:

```
def power(x, y):
  if y == 0: 
      return 1
  a = f(x*x, y//2) 
  if y % 2 == 1:
    a = x*a
  return a
```

How can I mathematically prove that it always works?

Answer (score 2):

The correctness of recursive algorithms is almost always proved through induction. Show that the base case works, and then show that if the algorithm works for any `y` up to some value `a`, then it also works for `a+1`.